# How to pass array values to a C# web service method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, rest

I am new to asp.net. From my client project I have to pass array values to a web service method. The web service part is in different project.

```
Public class Invoice
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}

    public string[] desc {get; set;}
    public int[] items {get; set; }
}
```

And  my controller part is

```
Invoice pe = new Invoice();

    pe.Name = "hubino";
        pe.Age = 21;

        pe.desc[0] = "Hundreds";
        pe.desc[1] = "chumma";
        pe.items[0] = 123;
        pe.items[1] = 45;
        pe.items[2] = 98;
```

How to pass the 'pe' variable to my web service method. I tried a lot to find a solution but failed. Please help me to solve this. If I am doing it wrong anywhere in the code please point out the errors.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your web service familiar with Invoice? Have you access to the code of web service?

Comment: @AdilMammadov I can create the same Invoice class in my web service and use that in my client project . But how to pass the array?

Comment: @RahulNikate I tried the way you said "service.TakeList(pe);" but it shows NullReferenceException 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'.

Comment: @Manoj Have you initialized the service object in "service.TakeList(pe);"

Comment: @RahulNikate I used the same Invoice class (which is in my question) but it shows error. And service is the object of Webservice method.

Comment: Null reference exception is because you have not initialized arrays. You should do this:
    pe.Name = "hubino";
    pe.Age = 21;
    pe.desc = new string[2];
    pe.items = new int[3];

Comment: @AdilMammadov What to do if I am not sure about my array size?

Comment: Yes, as @AntP mentioned, instead of string[] and int[] use List<string> and List<int> respectively

Comment: @Manoj You can do like this. pe.desc[] = new string[]{"Hundreds","Chumma"}; and same for pe.items array

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys. What to do if I have a class file only on my client side. In that case how can I send my array values to the web service method?

Comment: You need to modify web service method signature. Another option is that you can send values comma separated like "hundreds,chumma" which is not good programming practice

Comment: 'You need to modify web service method signature' how can I do that?. Please help me..

Comment: Ask who has developed that web service. ask for source of web service, so you can modify and re-deploy service again

Comment: @RahulNikate Actually I developed the web service by following some tutorials. I can't get your point on 'You need to modify web service method signature'. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Show me web service method

Comment: [WebMethod]
    public void TakeList(Invoice theList)
    {
        var charts = theList;
    }
This is the webmethod for Invoice class. Now how to pass array if i dont have any class in webmethod?

Comment: When i tried pe.items = new List<int>(); after changing this public int[] items {get; set; } to public List<int> items {get; set;}. But it shows Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'int[]'

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Invoice` class object initialization like below:

```
Invoice pe = new Invoice();

    pe.Name = "hubino";
    pe.Age = 21;

    pe.desc[] = new string[]{"Hundreds","Chumma"};
    pe.items[] = new int[]{123,45,98};
```

Also, Ant P & Adil Mammadov suggested to use `List<int>` and `List<string>`.

Comment: Can you please add the List declaration in the answer.

Comment: When i tried pe.items = new List<int>(); after changing this public int[] items {get; set; } to public List<int> items {get; set;}. But it shows Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'int[]'